# fstream object pointer

Tags: visual-c++, object, pointers, mfc

I have declared three object pointers fstream *output, fstream *input and dialog1 *dlg.  and dialog1.h is included.

```
#include<fstream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "dialog1.h"
fstream *output;
fstream *input;
dialog1 *dlg
```

error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'(about dialog)
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
Q: when i build the project errors like missing ";" comes out about *input and *output and about *dlg syntax error const comes out. What is the way to declare these objects?

Comment: The exact error messages and code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define a class in dialog1.h and forget the trailing semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forget to add std:: prefix to your declarations.

```
std::fstream *output;
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler ignores headers that comes before `#include "stdafx.h"`. So your `#include <fstream>` has no effect, please include it after `"#include "stdafx"`.